# Webclient.DownloadFileCompleted event failed

Tags: c#, webclient

I am downloading a large file from a web site.

Size: = 599 MB (629,113,799 bytes).

The program works fine.
However I run into some errors:

1. not able to validate that the file was completely donwloaded.
   I did not see any of the messages in the screen that says

   ```
   Console.WriteLine("..............File succesfully downloaded......This mesage comes from --  wc_DownloadFileCompleted..........");
   ```
2. So the program does download the file completely. 
   (I did download the file manually using the web browser and compared the
   file size between the manual download and the file that was downloaded
   via the program. The size was the same. So that is a good reason for me 
   to believe that the program did download the file completely)

   However at the very end (after it displays the percentage as 99)
   it throws an error.. Here is the message

   > An exception occured during a WebClient request.

   The error message gets fired inside the `wc_DownloadFileCompleted`
   method.

   So the help I need is... How do we validate that the file was downloaded
   completely (without any errors)? Also how do we eliminate the error.

   Is there some other code that I can use instead of using the code
   I presented.
3. I did see the File Download percentage 99 appear in the screen.
   However I did not see the "100" appear. Any comments?

---

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection; //Need this to get the DEBUG path
using MHPUtil;
using System.Net;
using System.Globalization;

namespace CmsNpiFileLoad
{
    public static class FileDownLoadPercentage
    {
        //We need a global variable that will remain the same throughout the run.
        //The unique value for this variable will get set in the DownloadFile() method.
        public static string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class CMsNPIFileDownLoad
    {
        //599 MB (629,113,799 bytes) is the size of the file.

        public void DownloadCMSNPIFile()
        {

            string Destinationfile = "S:\\MIS\\Provider NPI file\\" + "NPI.zip";
            string CmsDownLoadSite = "http://download.cms.gov/nppes/NPPES_Data_Dissemination_January_2018.zip";

            //Is the INTERNET AVAILABLE 
            if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internet available, proceed with the download");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Internet not available, proceed with the download");
                return;
            }

            //So at this point we dont have that file with us locally.. so lets download
            Console.WriteLine("Start Downloading....");
            try
            {
                using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.DownloadProgressChanged += wc_DownloadProgressChanged; // This works well 
                    client.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
                    client.DownloadFileAsync(new System.Uri(CmsDownLoadSite), Destinationfile);
                }
            }
            catch (WebException we)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(we.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine(); // We dont want the black screen to just disapper from us. so we put a readline so that it will keep displaying all the messsages

        }

        private static void wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The download has been cancelled");
                return;
            }

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //I tested the the program 2 times.. each time an error occured.
                //The error message is "An exceptipon occured during a WebClient request.
                Console.WriteLine("An error ocurred while trying to download file");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Error.Message.ToString());
                return;
            }

            // I did not see this on the screen.. ????
            Console.WriteLine("..............File succesfully downloaded......This mesage comes from --  wc_DownloadFileCompleted..........");
        }

        private static void wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            if (FileDownLoadPercentage.Value != e.ProgressPercentage.ToString())
            {
                FileDownLoadPercentage.Value = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString();

                //Display File Donwload Percentage ( increments of 10 ) 
                if (Convert.ToInt16(e.ProgressPercentage) % 10 == 0)
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());

                //Show the percentage when it is 99
                if (Convert.ToInt16(e.ProgressPercentage) == 99)
                    Console.WriteLine(e.ProgressPercentage.ToString());
            }


            if (e.BytesReceived == e.TotalBytesToReceive)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File DownLoad Complete...This message comes from --  wc_DownloadProgressChanged  "); // I did not see this on the screen.. ????
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Console application written in C#]

Comment: Why are you using ToInt16 on a file that is 629,113,799 bytes?

Comment: Why do your haved a virus in your project? See : http://www.completelyuninstallprogram.com/mhputil-dll/

Comment: reply to jdweng: 1.) MHPUTIL.dll is not a virus. It is a custom dll that was written by me ( But I can remove that .. However that will not solve the issue.  2.) The percentage change is a number between 1 and 100. So it is perfectly OK to use ToInt16.  Ok I can change this and  try.

Comment: So I changed the code to "Convert.ToInt32", tried to run the program but it gives the same error. Downloads 99% of the file but never reaches the 100% point. I tried to attach an image of the output, but StackOverflow said that I could not do so because I did not have enough points.

Comment: @user7015474 Image attached.

Comment: @user7015474 Is there an `InnerException` present? if so, what does it say?

Comment: Comparing file sizes isn't a good way of verifying two files are the same. You should hash the files to generate a checksum, then compare those.

Comment: @user7015474 I just tested your code *(took a while since the file is ~600MB)* I got `File succesfully downloaded` message.

Comment: tried one more time following some new syntax. This time I got rid of the `client.DownloadFileCompleted += wc_DownloadFileCompleted;` Added the following: `client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(wc_DownloadProgressChanged); `  , Gave it a run.. I am not getting errors, however the last percentage it shows is 99. So the download is yet incomplete.

Comment: @user7015474 No, once at 100% the `DownloadFileCompleted ` is triggered and not `DownloadProgressChanged `. You shouldn't expect percentage to tell you when the download is complete but in fact listen for `DownloadFileCompleted` which WILL trigger when the download is complete.

Comment: @Eric: Not sure how I may capture the  `InnerException` Can you send me a line of code that I can include and then I can run and reply back to you.

Comment: This may be not related to the issue. But I thought worthwhile mentioning. I had to modify the app.config file as follows. By doing this I was able to overcome some security issues. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
    </startup>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" >
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  
</configuration>`

Comment: Any `Exception` may have an `InnerException`. You can access it by `exception.InnerException` in your `try/catch`.

Comment: @mason Agree with you. In this case I am downloading a zip file. So I tried to extract the file ( using winzip ), gave me an error. So I know the download was inclomplete. As for comparing checksums ( I am not sure how to implement that )

Comment: I see you're downloading NPI's from CMS. I too have had to do that for my job. However, they don't provide a checksum on their site, so you have no way of knowing if you downloaded the file exactly as they provided it. But my checksum advice still holds true: if you download the file two different times, then comparing file sizes won't be accurate. You need do the checksums. There are command line utilities for Windows, such as [Microsoft File Checksum Integrity Verifier](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11533).

Comment: @Eric
`if (e.Error != null)... Console.WriteLine(e.Error.InnerException.Message.ToString()    );..`

**Unable to read data from the transport connection: An exisitingconnection was forcibly closed by the remote host.**

Comment: @Mason No problem. In this case we download a zip file. I also have C# code to unzip the file. While Unzipping the file if it throws an error then we know the file download was incomplete.

Comment: @Eric I did post the message that I get via the Inner Exception. Hope you can shed some light here. Hoping to hear.

Comment: @user7015474 It seems the server closes connection before the download completes. Perhaps due to your slow internet connection. This didn't happen in my case, I have 200/200 Mbit connection speed.

Comment: @Eric I am running this in an computer in a corporate environment ( I believe there are firewalls and other security layers). Anyhow I will try running this at home ( or some other environment) and check whether it will make a difference ( That fact is even if I try to download this file using Google Chrome, it fails, then I have to go to the "downloads" page and hit the resume button and the download is complete )